# How do i get this object to print out in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently working on a project in angularJS, and I'm shuffling around how our system works a little bit, but for whatever reason the new return isn't being displayed in angular..
Here's what my html looks like..

```
<button ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-click="setCompany(company)">
                {{ company.name }}
            </button>
```

Also, here's a snippet of code from my js file.

```
 $.post( "/turnup/index.php/app/companies_near", data,
        function(response)
        {
          $scope.companies = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log($scope.companies);
        } );
```

but for whatever reason it isn't printing out my object that has the following structure..

```
[Object]
0: Object
distance: "0.00006317660849859675"
id: "2"
name: "Pi Kappa Alpha - Epsilon Chapter"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
concat: function concat() { [native code] }
constructor: function Array() { [native code] }
every: function every() { [native code] }
filter: function filter() { [native code] }
forEach: function forEach() { [native code] }
indexOf: function indexOf() { [native code] }
join: function join() { [native code] }
lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() { [native code] }
length: 0
map: function map() { [native code] }
pop: function pop() { [native code] }
push: function push() { [native code] }
reduce: function reduce() { [native code] }
reduceRight: function reduceRight() { [native code] }
reverse: function reverse() { [native code] }
shift: function shift() { [native code] }
slice: function slice() { [native code] }
some: function some() { [native code] }
sort: function sort() { [native code] }
splice: function splice() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
unshift: function unshift() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: why are you using jquery post request instead of angular's `$http` service and promises?

Comment: I was having trouble with using it with codeigniter (pretty new to angular). and i've got to rush this project unfortunately.

Comment: you need to $apply your changes after updating your companies because your post is outside the angular digest cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using jquery instead of the angular $http service. Angular doesn't detect changes from requests of external requests such as jquery. If you want to use jquery instead of $http for whatever reason you will need to call $scope.apply() to tell angular that a value has changed.

This should work

```
    $.post( "/turnup/index.php/app/companies_near", data,
        function(response)
        {
             $scope.$apply(function(){
                  $scope.companies = JSON.parse(response);
             });
        });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: Worked.. I also had to fetch the scope variable. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must call `$scope.$apply();` in the callback when the HTTP request completes, otherwise AngularJS won't know anything changed.

If you use the built-in `$http` this would happen automagically.

More details: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 0):

you need to $apply your changes after updating your companies because your post is outside the angular digest cycle.
so you do

```
$scope.$apply();
```

after your assignment that should do it. how ever try to work out the $http issue, it would be a lot cleaner and easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular, definitely prefer $http over $.post:

```
 $http({ url:'/turnup/index.php/app/companies_near', method:'POST'})
 .success(data) {
      $scope.companies = data;
      console.log($scope.companies);
 });
```